# Start a new activity clearing the activity stack

Tags: java, android

In order to block the application when it detects that is not a licensed version I'd like to start a new activity clearing the current stack, thats is:
if the stack have the activities [A,B,C,D]  i want to start the activity E leaving the stack with only [E].

I'm playing with the intent extras FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK with no success

Comment: Ive heard problems, when people used those intent extras, but they didnt work. Some of them were fixed by cleaning project, restarting eclipse and/or emulator. Its worth trying, as those FLAGs should work.

Comment: Post relevant code and define "no success". The flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` should have worked for what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a parent activity which is overriding the `OnNewIntent`, when receving an intent with `EXIT` extra finishes itself.note that you have to call it with the SINGLE_TOP flag, so the `OnNewIntent` will be called.

then create a static method which broadcast an exit intent to all of your activities that inharnace this parent activity.

This should work even if you have move than one tasks.